# mapping samba share via a PS1 script not working

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell

so I made a .ps1 script which I can run anytime I want to map my samba share.

When I ran the PS1 script, it asked me for my password but I cannot change directory to the shared folder. I tried this twice.

But when I copy and paste the contents of my PS1 file into powershell and run that instead, I was able to change directory to the samba share.

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Please a look at this:

```
PS D:\myscripts> .\map-myfileserver1.ps1

Name           Used (GB)     Free (GB) Provider      Root                                               CurrentLocation
----           ---------     --------- --------      ----                                               ---------------
y                5371.89        682.30 FileSystem    \\myfileserver1\smb-storage


PS D:\myscripts> y:
Set-Location : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'Y' does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-Location $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Y:String) [Set-Location], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand

PS D:\myscripts> .\map-myfileserver1.ps1

Name           Used (GB)     Free (GB) Provider      Root                                               CurrentLocation
----           ---------     --------- --------      ----                                               ---------------
y                5371.89        682.30 FileSystem    \\myfileserver1\smb-storage


PS D:\myscripts> y:
Set-Location : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'Y' does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-Location $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Y:String) [Set-Location], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand

PS D:\myscripts> new-psdrive -name y -psprovider filesystem -root \\myfileserver1\smb-storage -credential my-samba-user-here -persist

Name           Used (GB)     Free (GB) Provider      Root                                               CurrentLocation
----           ---------     --------- --------      ----                                               ---------------
y                5371.89        682.30 FileSystem    \\myfileserver1\smb-storage


PS D:\myscripts> y:
PS y:\>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `-scope global` to the cmdlet invocation in your script. Without it, the drive is unmapped when the script exits. Seems counterintuitive when already using `-persist`, but that's what it takes.

```
help new-psdrive -details
-Scope <String>
    Specifies a scope for the drive. Valid values are "Global", "Local", or "Script", or a
    number relative to the current scope (0 through the number of scopes, where 0 is the
    current scope and 1 is its parent). "Local" is the default. For more information, see
    about_Scopes (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113260).
```